# Is it bad to put operations inside #{these}?

Tags: ruby

Like this:

`puts "Today my ostrich laid #{@eggs_laid - @stillborn - @wolves_ate} valid eggs."`

If this was literally the only place I'd be needing this specific calculation, is there any point in making a `valid_eggs` function?

Comment: I know I've put down an answer, but really this isn't a constructive question. It's such a simple statement that it could go both ways, anything more complex and most people will recommend extraction. I tend to have a working practice where, if I come back to such code after a while and it isn't **instantly** clear what it does, then it is worth extracting because It's proven to be lacking in clarity.

Comment: You and several other very high rep users *all* answered, instead of casting your close votes. This is *completely* subjective, to the point where the top-voted answer, by a 71k rep user, starts with "This is an opinion". This is expressly *not* what Stack Overflow is for.

Comment: Correction - I did cast a close vote, just before adding my comment.

Comment: Your code has two responsibilities, calculating `valid_eggs` and printing / formatting a line. You should separate the calculation from the presentation.

Comment: @maegar: Completely subjective? I think that the user very clearly says "If this was literelly the only place", and asks about making `valid_eggs` method. I think that "No" answer is completely obvious, which even the user knows: Ze wants a commented "No".

Comment: @BorisStitnicky No, it's completely subjective. I would make a method. Given we're using instance `@variables`, I'm assuming we're inside a class, and I would expect the calculation of `eggs_left` to be a simple class method. Your own answer expresses a completely different opinion than mine, and *neither* opinion is more correct because it's *completely subjective*.

Comment: @maegar: Cool down and notice yourself. You used the word "opinion" twice, and "completely" thrice. Churches and postmodern governments have demonstrated enough, that "everything is just a matter of opinion", so you don't have to.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I don't think there's anything obvious about a "no" answer. I'd tend towards a method as well because the expression has a business-logic-smell, and as such, I find it testable, hence isolatable. Let's keep the intra-personal stuff elsewhere.

Comment: I answered the question because even though it's an opinion piece I think knowing the tradeoffs is valuable. I don't find that this question would lead to extended discussions because of its simplicity, so while I think closure is okay, I also think answering it is informative/educational.

Answer (score 5):

It's not inherently bad. But if the expression is complex, it reduces readability of the code. Here, I put the two snippets here, which one reads better?

```
puts "Today my ostrich laid #{@eggs_laid - @stillborn - @wolves_ate} valid eggs."

valid_eggs = @eggs_laid - @stillborn - @wolves_ate
puts "Today my ostrich laid #{valid_eggs} valid eggs."
```

Comment: Is it really worth having a temporary variable that is used in one place instead of a perfectly readable set of actions. I agree that there are places where it would be more readable, but in this case it is debateable.

Comment: @Abizern Possibly, yes: it *is* readable inside the string. But it's inside the string, and there's a cognitive switch involved I'd generally rather avoid.

Comment: @Abizern: I would extract that expression into local var, if that's what you're asking. Makes the string easier to read.

Comment: And I wouldn't be offended by it. :)

Comment: See, that's the thing; the second one does look nicer, but it is technically longer and, since I'm only doing the calculation one time, also unnecessary.

Comment: "it's technically longer" - do you run out of ink, I wonder? :) Why sacrifice readability for brevity?

Answer (score 5):

This is an opinion piece: yes and no.

If it's "complex"<sup>1</sup> it likely belongs somewhere else.

If it's "simple"<sup>2</sup> it's not an issue.

It all comes down to readability, maintainability, appropriate re-use, and not doing anything silly.

---

<sup>1. For varying values of "complex".
2. For varying values of "simple".</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely not. Putting code inside `#{...}` interpolators is a legitimate part of fun in Ruby. For readability, you might consider:

```
puts "Today my ostrich laid %s valid eggs." % ( @eggs_laid - @stillborn - @wolves_ate )
```

But note that `%` interpolation and `#{...}` interpolation are two different kinds of fun, which are not fully interchangeable.

Comment: *+1* for this answer and specially for mentioning *% interpolation and #{...} interpolation are two different kinds of fun*.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is clear - at least your variable names make sense. A purist may say you should extract it to a method - but really - YAGNI (You Ain't Gonna Need It) also applies to ruby.

If you need to do it in a second place then I would make it a method. You've already thought about it.

Comment: Right on. I was just wondering if there was some kind of taboo.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously this is debatable, as other answer states.

One case in which you should definitely extract operations is when they have side effects.

As long as expression is referentially transparent it is only matter of taste and subjective readability.

Comment: What do you mean "when they have side effects"?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_(computer_science)